# Python / Raspberry Pi script does not show keyboard input after quitting

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am somewhat new to python / raspberry Pi.  I am creating a little music clip launcher using omxplayer & the readchar library.  Basically hit a key, and it plays 5 second loops.  I run the script from the command line, and once it quits, I can't see any keyboard input.  I know that the terminal is still reading the keyboard strokes, as I can type a number of characters, hit enter, and it will still run the commands.  I'm guessing I need to reset STDIO before actually quitting the program?  Any input appreciated. (sorry, pun slightly intended)

```
import readchar
import subprocess
import signal
import os
import sys
import time

while 1:
    key = readchar.readkey()
    if key == 'q':             
        break
    elif key == 'm':
        pro = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local','/home/pi/Music/Disc 2 - Rap Jazzy/06. Q-Tip ft. Heavy D - Listen.flac'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        time.sleep(5)
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
    elif key == 'i':
        pro = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', '/home/pi/Music/Disc 2 - Rap Jazzy/02. Malik Yusef - Get Ready (Rmx).flac'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        time.sleep(5)
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
    else:
        print key
```

Comment: My best guess is that this very crude little library never gets to execute `termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)` - Which should reset the stdin of your terminal. You could do this manually and see if it works, before importing `readchar` do what they do, `old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)` and then execute the above at the end of your code.

Comment: It's crude, but try this: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/00c4820a420df1f12bcb191ea8ecaf01

Comment: thank you, i had tried something similar but must have got the wrong syntax.  Your suggestion worked, thank you very much.